# php searching function

Tags: php, mysql

hello please me out regarding this function . Its searching script. when i am passing integer to it it work and when i pass like 12eh it doesnt work . although i have kept varchar as a datatype so it can work for both

```
function view($pno)
{
$this->query=("select * from user where pno=$pno");
$rd = $this->executeQuery();
@$data = $rd->fetch_assoc();
return $data; 
}
```

Comment: add single quotes to work for nonintegers. also use something like `mysql_real_escape_chars` so you dont have an sqlinject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote your variable in the SQL query:

```
$this->query=("select * from user where pno = '$pno'");
```

Also you would probably do well to do:

```
$pno = mysql_escape_string($pno);
```

Before sticking the variable in your SQL statement. The [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) explains more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->query=("select * from user where pno='$pno'");
```

missing quotes around `$pno`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_escape_string() is deprecated in PHP 5.3. Use instead mysql_real_escape_string()

Code will be something like this:

```
$this->query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE pno = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($pno) . "'";
```